# Highest (green) and Lowest (red) coordinates plot using Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, linegraph

I am trying to achieve the line graph which shows the highest and lowest coordinates as green and red dots as shown below by using some jquery plugins. I have selected **[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org)** library since it is free and open source and it is responsive. I was able to create the line graph using the chart.js but the problem is that I was unable to do the following things

[image]

1. I need only lowest (red) and highest (green) coordinates under color dots within the graph, right now it is showing all coordinates under dots
2. Any option to hide the graph labeling.
3. How to show the highest and lowest coordinates below the graph

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/83dmx3s7/)**

**JavaScript**

```
var lineData = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        data: [69.4, 48.8, 99.4, 48.2, 10.3, 50.5]
    }]
}

var lineOptions = {
    animation: true,
    pointDot: true,
    scaleOverride : true,
    scaleShowGridLines : false,
    scaleShowLabels : false,
    scaleSteps : 4,
    scaleStepWidth : 25,
    scaleStartValue : 0,
};

//Create Line chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);
```

**Html**

```
<canvas id="lineChart" width="800" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the chart to do 1., use the `showScale` option to do 2. and use DOM manipulation (or your javascript library if it supports it) to do 3.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
...
<ul><li id="min"><span></span></li><li id="max"><span></span></li></ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#min, #max {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#min > span, #max > span {
    color: rgba(145,145,145,1);
}
#min {
    color: red;
}
#max {
    color: green;
}
```

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var max = Math.max.apply(null, data.datasets[0].data);
        document.getElementById("max").firstChild.innerText = max;
        var min = Math.min.apply(null, data.datasets[0].data);
        document.getElementById("min").firstChild.innerText = min;
        this.datasets[0].points.forEach(function (point) {
            if (point.value === max)
                point._saved.fillColor = point.highlightFill = point.fillColor = 'green';
            else if (point.value === min)
                point._saved.fillColor = point.highlightFill = point.fillColor = 'red';
            else
                point.inRange = function() { return false }
        })
    }
});
```

and then

```
    ...
    showScale: false,
};

//Create Line chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(lineData, lineOptions);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/py2mcfyk/2/

Comment: apart from the highest and lowest points the graph is showing coordinates of other points

Comment: You mean tooltips? Just make change the inRange function (see updated answer)